# How to read data from Cassandra with R?

Tags: r, cassandra

I am using R 2.14.1 and Cassandra 1.2.11, I have a separate program which has written  data to a single Cassandra table. I am failing to read them from R.

The Cassandra schema is defined like this:

```
create table chosen_samples (id bigint , temperature double, primary key(id))
```

I have first tried the RCassandra package (http://www.rforge.net/RCassandra/)

```
> # install.packages("RCassandra")
> library(RCassandra)
> rc <- RC.connect(host ="192.168.33.10", port = 9160L)
> RC.use(rc, "poc1_samples")
> cs <- RC.read.table(rc, c.family="chosen_samples")
```

The connection seems to succeed but the parsing of the table into data frame fails:

```
> cs
Error in data.frame(..dfd. = c("@\"ffffff", "@(<cc><cc><cc><cc><cc><cd>",  : 
  duplicate row.names:
```

I have also tried using JDBC connector, as described here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/big-analytics-with-r-cassandra-and-hive

```
> # install.packages("RJDBC")
> library(RJDBC)
> cassdrv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver", "/Users/svend/dev/libs/cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar", "`")
```

But this one fails like this:

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
```

Even though the location to the java driver is correct

```
$ ls /Users/svend/dev/libs/cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar
/Users/svend/dev/libs/cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar
```

Comment: You should update your ancient R version. The current version is 3.0.2.

Answer (score 5):

You have to download [apache-cassandra-2.0.10-bin.tar.gz](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/cassandra/2.0.10/apache-cassandra-2.0.10-bin.tar.gz) and [cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/downloads/list) and [cassandra-all-1.1.0.jar](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/1.1.0).

There is no need to install Cassandra on your local machine; just put the cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar and the cassandra-all-1.1.0.jar files in the lib directory of unziped apache-cassandra-2.0.10-bin.tar.gz. Then you can use

```
 library(RJDBC)
 drv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver", 
              list.files("D:/apache-cassandra-2.0.10/lib",
              pattern="jar$",full.names=T))
```

That is working on my unix but not on my windows machine.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Working on my Windows machine too. I downloaded the drivers from here: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/downloads/list and dependencies (BUT NOT THE DRIVER) from here: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/

Comment: Forgot to mention: for some reason, I have to execute the last command, JDBC(...) twice. The first time it fails; the second it succeeds.

Comment: I got the jdbc jar and dependencies from https://code.google.com/archive/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc

Answer (score 5):

This question is old now, but since it's the one of the top hits for R and Cassandra I thought I'd leave a simple solution here, as I found frustratingly little up-to-date support for what I thought would be a fairly common task.

Sparklyr makes this pretty easy to do from scratch now, as it exposes a java context so the `Spark-Cassandra-Connector` can be used directly.  I've wrapped up the bindings in this simple package, [crassy](https://github.com/AkhilNairAmey/crassy), but it's not necessary to use.

I mostly made it to demystify the config around how to make `sparklyr` load the connector, and as the syntax for selecting a subset of columns is a little unwieldy (assuming no Scala knowledge).

Column selection and partition filtering are supported. These were the only features I thought were necessary for general Cassandra use cases, given CQL can't be submitted directly to the cluster.

I've not found a solution to submitting more general CQL queries which doesn't involve writing custom scala, however there's an example of how this can work [here](https://github.com/AkhilNairAmey/CQLConnect).

Comment: how to connect to remote Cassandra in sparklyr?

Answer (score 3):

Right, I found an (admittedly ugly) way, simply by calling python from R, parsing the NA manually and re-assigning the data-frames names in R, like this

```
# install.packages("rPython")
# (don't forget to "pip install cql")
library(rPython)
python.exec("import sys")
# adding libraries from virtualenv 
python.exec("sys.path.append('/Users/svend/dev/pyVe/playground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')")
python.exec("import cql")

python.exec("connection=cql.connect('192.168.33.10', cql_version='3.0.0')")
python.exec("cursor = connection.cursor()")
python.exec("cursor.execute('use poc1_samples')")
python.exec("cursor.execute('select * from chosen_samples' )")

# coding python None into NA (rPython seem to just return nothing )
python.exec("rep = lambda x : '__NA__' if x is None else x")
python.exec( "def getData(): return [rep(num) for line in cursor for num in line ]" )
data <- python.call("getData")
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), ncol=15, byrow=T))

names(df) <- c("temperature", "maxTemp", "minTemp",
"dewpoint", "elevation", "gust", "latitude", "longitude",
"maxwindspeed", "precipitation", "seelevelpressure", "visibility", "windspeed")

# and decoding NA's    
parsena <- function (x) if (x=="__NA__") NA else x
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df,  parsena))
```

Anybody has a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when executing `Rscript` with `RJDBC` connection via batch file (R 3.2.4, Teradata driver).
Also, when run in `RStudio` it worked fine in the second run but not first.

What helped was explicitly call:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It not enough to just download the driver, you have to also download the dependencies and put them into your JAVA ClassPath (MacOS: /Library/Java/Extensions) as stated on the project [main page](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/).

> Include the Cassandra JDBC dependencies in your classpath : download dependencies

As of the RCassandra package, right now it's still too primitive compared to RJDBC.