# cassandra and R connection error

Tags: java, r, cassandra, rjava

I have already installed `rJava`, `DBI` and `RJDBC` package.

When I start the connection in the directory '/lib/cassandra/cassandra-jdbc-2.1-2/cassandra-2.1-2.jdbc41.jar' I am getting this error. I installed from a web site.

```
> library(rJava)
> library(RJDBC)
Loading required package: DBI
> library(DBI)
> library(RJDBC)
> cassandra_driver <- JDBC("com.datastax.driver.jdbc.CassandraDriver", 
                "/lib/cassandra/cassandra-jdbc-2.1-2/cassandra-2.1-2.jdbc41.jar")
```

*

> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

*

Comment: check out this: answer from fc9.30 and comments by user1225054 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994077/how-to-read-data-from-cassandra-with-r ... do vote up their answer/comments if it helps you