# R and cassandra connection error

Tags: r, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, rjdbc

```
library(RJDBC)




cassdrv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver",
                    list.files("/home/beyhan/Downloads/jars/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T))

    casscon <- dbConnect(cassdrv, "jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042")
```

Output

```
> cassdrv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver",
+ list.files("/home/beyhan/Downloads/jars/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T))
> casscon <- dbConnect(cassdrv, "jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042")
```

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect",
>   as.character(url)[1],  :    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportException

Comment: Are you using windows machine?

Comment: no,using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the ODBC Connector is based on the THRIFT Protocol. The THRIFT Connection to Cassandra is deprecated. I think the Python in solution is the best approach for you. Here a example: [How to read data from Cassandra with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994077/how-to-read-data-from-cassandra-with-r)

And here is a blog post about Thrift vs. CQL: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-2-1-now-over-50-faster

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i want to connecct with R.SO what should i do ? Also i have already tried RCassandra

Comment: Have you checked the Thrift Port? 9160 instead of 9042

Answer (score 0):

Our JDBC Driver for Cassandra allows you to access your Cassandra data in R. To be clear, our driver creates a relational interface to your Cassandra data, allowing you to submit SQL queries to Cassandra through our driver (internally, we translate the SQL to CQL, send the request and return the results as a relational database).

We have an [article](http://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cassandra-jdbc-r.rst) in our Knowledge Base for connecting, but I'll transcribe it here as well.

1. Load the RJDBC Package:

   ```
   library(RJDBC)
   ```
2. Set the driver class and classpath:

   ```
   driver <- JDBC(driverClass = "cdata.jdbc.cassandra.CassandraDriver", classPath = "MyInstallationDir\lib\cdata.jdbc.cassandra.jar", identifier.quote = "'")
   ```
3. Initialize the JDBC connection:

   ```
   conn <- dbConnect(driver,"Database=MyCassandraDB;Port=7000;Server=127.0.0.1;")
   ```

   (Set the Server, Port, and Database connection properties to connect to Cassandra.)

At this point, you can perform standards actions available in R, like:

- Listing the tables:

  ```
  dbListTables(conn)
  ```
- Executing any SQL query supported by the Cassandra API:

  ```
  customer <- dbGetQuery(conn,"SELECT City, SUM(TotalDue) FROM Customer GROUP BY City")
  ```
- Viewing the results:

  ```
  View(customer)
  ```

Feel free to download a [free Beta](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/cassandra/download/jdbc) of the driver! If you have any questions, please let us know.

Comment: Unable to connect JDBC to Database=MyCassandraDB;Port=9160;Server=127.0.0.1; I got this error at the 3.step , tried 700,9042 but all of this gave error

Comment: @BeyhanGül You'll need to configure the properties based on the machine hosting the Cassandra database and the database you wish to connect to. While I'm happy to help debug minor issues here, if you continue to run into errors, our [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) will be happy to help.