# R cassandra odbc error

Tags: r, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spark-cassandra-connector, bigdata

when i am linking up R and Cassandra with the RODBC library, i am getting below error

> Warning messages:
>       1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DSN=/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cdata.jdbc.cassandra.jar")
>   :
>       [RODBC] ERROR: state IM012, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]DRIVER keyword syntax error 2: In
>   RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DSN=/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cdata.jdbc.cassandra.jar")
>   :
>       ODBC connection failed

And my code is there:

```
library(RODBC)

con <-odbcConnect("DSN=/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cdata.jdbc.cassandra.jar")
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that you're trying to use the CData JDBC Driver with RODBC. We produce separate JDBC and ODBC drivers for Cassandra, but either will allow you access your Cassandra data in R.

You can review [this article](http://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cassandra-odbc-r.rst) for connecting to Cassandra in R using our ODBC driver, though I've included the relevant steps below:

1. Configure the DSN

   If you have not already, first specify connection properties in an ODBC DSN (data source name). This is the last step of the driver installation. You can use the Microsoft ODBC Data Source Administrator to create and configure ODBC DSNs.

   Set the Server, Port, and Database connection properties to connect to Cassandra. Additionally, to use internal authentication set the User and Password connection properties.
2. Load the RODBC Package

   ```
   library(RODBC)
   ```
3. Create a connection to your Cassandra data, using the name of the DSN you configured above

   ```
   conn <- odbcConnect("CData Cassandra Source")
   ```

Once you've established the connection to your Cassandra data, you can perform all manner of operations in R, including:

- Schema discovery

  ```
  sqlTables(conn)
  ```
- Executing SQL queries and view the results

  ```
  customer <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT City, SUM(TotalDue) FROM Customer GROUP BY City", believeNRows=FALSE, rows_at_time=1)
  View(customer)
  ```
- Plot Cassandra data

  ```
  par(las=2,ps=10,mar=c(5,15,4,2))
  barplot(customer$TotalDue, main="Cassandra Customer", names.arg = customer$City, horiz=TRUE)
  ```

Comment: i downloaded new odbc but it's .exe but i am using ubuntu

Comment: I see. In that case, you'll need to use our JDBC driver. I believe we've already discussed that option in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133209).